# Parsing query like string to array

Tags: php, parsing

i have a string that looks like this:

```
$query = '(((306352743) and (306354310 OR 306354381 OR 306354379 OR 306354383 OR 306354372 OR 306354371 OR 306354378 OR 306354384 OR 306354373 OR 306354375 OR 306354376 OR 306354377 OR 306354382 OR 306354380 OR 306354374)) and ((306348630 OR 306347920) and (306348630)))';
```

and i want to parse it in to some kind of array that i can easly loop through.
any sugestions?

Comment: What output do you expect for this input?

Comment: Do you want to follow the logic (i.e.: the ANDs or ORs), or simply parse out the values, or ?

Comment: @sjngm Thanks for the proclamation!

Comment: woeps diddent even know there was a accept ratio. i will accept the answers in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would try, is using string functions to replace all parens with square brackets, then wrap each number or word in quotes, then inserting a comma between each, until you have a string that you can use with json_decode() to parse into an array.